# Make linkserver in openquery a variable picked from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple linked servers in my SQL Server database.
I created a procedure to identify the Primary Host

```
EXEC [Schema].[Server]
```

This procedure returns a table 'ServerTable' with only one line

```
------------------
| - |   Server
------------------
| 1 | server_name
------------------
```

Now I would like to create a view using OPENQUERY and the one item in 'ServerTable'

```
USE [Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [Schema].[View] AS

SELECT 
    *
FROM OPENQUERY (
    server_name,  <-- variable to be updated depending on 'ServerTable' item
    'SELECT *
     FROM "_SYS_BIC"."system-local.bw.bw2hana/WHC_CP03"'
     )

;

GO
```

Comment: The dynamic SQL solutions proposed as answers will not work if you need a view, as you can't stuff dynamic SQL into a view. Consider generating your *views* dynamically, or set up a linked server and use synonyms to the linked server objects. If the remote server in question is a SQL Server, you can use `sp_setnetname` to make the server something other than the name you're using (but I'm pretty sure you can't redirect instance names that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parametrise OPENQUERY calls so you have use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT 
    *
FROM OPENQUERY (
    ' + server_name + '
    ', ''SELECT *
     FROM "_SYS_BIC"."system-local.bw.bw2hana/WHC_CP03"''
     )'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it always only returns one value, you can use OUTPUT.

Something like...

```
create procedure [Schema].[Server]
    @someParameter theDataType,
    @outPutParameter varchar(64) output
as
begin
    select @outPutParameter = someColumn
    from sys.servers
    where someColumn = @someParameter 
          and isLinkedServer = 1
end
```

Or, if you return multiple lines you can store it in a table

```
create table #temp([Server] char(64))
insert into #temp
exec [Schema].[Server]


declare @server char(64) = (select top 1 [Server] from #temp)
```

Then, just use @server in your openquery with dynamic sql